# Yocto variable not defined but set with _ operator

Tags: stm32, yocto, bitbake

I'm struggling with something I'm not sure to address correctly.

In a Yocto environment (for STM32MP1 by the way) I have to configure a new target. 
Hence I added to `meta-st/meta-st-stm32mp/conf/machine/include/st-machine-extlinux-config-stm32mp.inc` this section, that looks like the other already available:

```
EXTLINUX_BOOTDEVICE_EMMC      = "mmc1"
EXTLINUX_BOOTDEVICE_SDCARD    = "mmc0"

EXTLINUX_ROOT_EMMC         = "${@bb.utils.contains('ST_VENDORFS','1','root=/dev/mmcblk1p4','root=/dev/mmcblk1p3',d)}"
EXTLINUX_ROOT_NAND         = "ubi.mtd=UBI rootfstype=ubifs root=ubi0:rootfs"

# Define available targets to use
UBOOT_EXTLINUX_CONFIGURED_TARGETS += "mp151a_sdcard"
UBOOT_EXTLINUX_CONFIGURED_TARGETS += "mp151a_emmc"

# Define bootprefix for each target
UBOOT_EXTLINUX_BOOTPREFIXES_mp151a_sdcard       = "${EXTLINUX_BOOTDEVICE_SDCARD}_stm32mp151a_"
UBOOT_EXTLINUX_BOOTPREFIXES_mp151a_emcc       = "${EXTLINUX_BOOTDEVICE_EMCC}_stm32mp151a_"

# Define labels for each target
UBOOT_EXTLINUX_LABELS_mp151a_sdcard       = "stm32mp151a-sdcard"
UBOOT_EXTLINUX_LABELS_mp151a_emcc       = "stm32mp151a-emcc"

# Define default boot config for each target
UBOOT_EXTLINUX_DEFAULT_LABEL_mp151a_sdcard       ?= "stm32mp151a-sdcard"
UBOOT_EXTLINUX_DEFAULT_LABEL_mp151a_emcc       ?= "stm32mp151a-emcc"

# Define FDT overrides for all labels
UBOOT_EXTLINUX_FDT_stm32mp151a-sdcard       = "/stm32mp151a.dtb"
UBOOT_EXTLINUX_FDT_stm32mp151a-emcc       = "/stm32mp151a.dtb"

# Define ROOT overrides for all labels
UBOOT_EXTLINUX_ROOT_stm32mp151a-sdcard       = "${EXTLINUX_ROOT_SDCARD}"
UBOOT_EXTLINUX_ROOT_stm32mp151a-emcc       = "${EXTLINUX_ROOT_EMCC}"
```

But when I `bitbake <image>` (that includes the file above) I get this output:

```
DEBUG: Executing python function update_extlinuxconf_targets
NOTE: UBOOT_EXTLINUX_CONFIGURED_TARGETS:  mp157a-dk1_sdcard mp157a-dk1_sdcard-optee mp157c-dk2_sdcard mp157c-dk2_sdcard-optee mp157c-ed1_emmc mp157c-ed1_emmc-optee mp157c-ed1_sdcard mp157c-ed1_sdcard-optee mp157c-ev1_emmc mp157c-ev1_emmc-optee mp157c-ev1_nand mp157c-ev1_nor-sdcard mp157c-ev1_nor-emmc mp157c-ev1_sdcard mp157c-ev1_sdcard-optee mp151a_sdcard mp151a_emmc
NOTE: UBOOT_EXTLINUX_CONFIG_FLAGS:  emmc    sdcard
NOTE: *** Loop for config_label: emmc
NOTE: *** Loop for devicetree: stm32mp151a
NOTE: >>> New target label: mp151a_emmc
NOTE: >>> Append mp151a_emmc to UBOOT_EXTLINUX_TARGETS
NOTE: *** Loop for config_label: sdcard
NOTE: *** Loop for devicetree: stm32mp151a
NOTE: >>> New target label: mp151a_sdcard
NOTE: >>> Append mp151a_sdcard to UBOOT_EXTLINUX_TARGETS
NOTE: >>> UBOOT_EXTLINUX_TARGETS (updated):  mp151a_emmc mp151a_sdcard
DEBUG: Python function update_extlinuxconf_targets finished
DEBUG: Executing python function do_create_multiextlinux_config
ERROR: UBOOT_EXTLINUX_ROOT not defined
DEBUG: Python function do_create_multiextlinux_config finished
ERROR: Function failed: do_create_multiextlinux_config
```

As you can see, the file is actually processed because it added the targets I've defined.
But it doesn't find the `UBOOT_EXTLINUX_ROOT` even if it's "set" with the `_` operator:

```
UBOOT_EXTLINUX_ROOT_stm32mp151a-sdcard       = "${EXTLINUX_ROOT_SDCARD}"
UBOOT_EXTLINUX_ROOT_stm32mp151a-emcc       = "${EXTLINUX_ROOT_EMCC}"
```

I also tried to set the main variable to something like:

```
UBOOT_EXTLINUX_ROOT = ""
```

or

```
UBOOT_EXTLINUX_ROOT = "root=/dev/mmcblk1p4"
```

to see if it was the problem but it doesn't change nothing.
Is this something related to Yocto itself (I mean, something wrong in my syntax) or it's very specific to the SDK (`meta-st`) ?

The error above should be raised by [this](https://github.com/openembedded/openembedded-core/blob/master/meta/classes/uboot-extlinux-config.bbclass) file:

```
root = localdata.getVar('UBOOT_EXTLINUX_ROOT')
if not root:
    bb.fatal('UBOOT_EXTLINUX_ROOT not defined')
```

### UPDATE

I checked the (huge) output of `bitbake -e` and among other targets I see:

```
# $UBOOT_EXTLINUX_ROOT [41 operations]
[...]
#     "${EXTLINUX_ROOT_NOREMMC}"
#   override[stm32mp157c-ev1-m4-examples-sdcard]:set /local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.1.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-10-09/layers/meta-st/meta-st-stm32mp/conf/machine/include/st-machine-extlinux-config-stm32mp.inc:274
#     "${EXTLINUX_ROOT_SDCARD}"
#   override[stm32mp157c-ev1-m4-examples-sdcard-optee]:set /local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.1.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-10-09/layers/meta-st/meta-st-stm32mp/conf/machine/include/st-machine-extlinux-config-stm32mp.inc:275
#     "${EXTLINUX_ROOT_SDCARD_OPTEE}"
#   override[stm32mp151a-sdcard]:set /local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.1.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-10-09/layers/meta-st/meta-st-stm32mp/conf/machine/include/st-machine-extlinux-config-stm32mp.inc:296
#     "${EXTLINUX_ROOT_SDCARD}"
#   override[stm32mp151a-emcc]:set /local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.1.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-10-09/layers/meta-st/meta-st-stm32mp/conf/machine/include/st-machine-extlinux-config-stm32mp.inc:297
[...]
# pre-expansion value:
#   ""
UBOOT_EXTLINUX_ROOT=""

# $UBOOT_EXTLINUX_ROOT_cubemx-nor-sdcard
UBOOT_EXTLINUX_ROOT_cubemx-nor-sdcard="root=/dev/mmcblk0p3"
# $UBOOT_EXTLINUX_ROOT_cubemx-sdcard
UBOOT_EXTLINUX_ROOT_cubemx-sdcard="root=/dev/mmcblk0p6"
# $UBOOT_EXTLINUX_ROOT_stm32mp151a-emcc
UBOOT_EXTLINUX_ROOT_stm32mp151a-emcc="\${EXTLINUX_ROOT_EMCC}"
# $UBOOT_EXTLINUX_ROOT_stm32mp151a-sdcard
UBOOT_EXTLINUX_ROOT_stm32mp151a-sdcard="root=/dev/mmcblk0p6"
```

So far, if I understand correctly, the override values are correctly assigned <s>(but not the `${EXTLINUX_ROOT_EMCC}` - I don't understand where the `\` comes from)</s> but the main variable is still empty.

Adding `UBOOT_EXTLINUX_ROOT = "root=/dev/mmcblk1p4"` at the beginning of the above file, seems to do the trick (even if before I wrote the opposite, perhaps I forgot to clear the cache?) but I don't think it's the right way to do it.

Comment: About the emmc I found a typo: `${EXTLINUX_ROOT_EMCC}` vs `${EXTLINUX_ROOT_EMMC}`

Comment: Is your problem solved then?

Comment: Of course, not. The only part solved is the one striked in the question - by the way a marginal one. Thanks,

Comment: Your `OVERRIDES` (such as from `MACHINEOVERRIDES`) must contain one of `stm32mp151a-sdcard` or `stm32mp151a-emmc`

Comment: @mrvulcan, thanks but I don't understand where I need to append them to `OVERRIDES`. I `grep` for this keyword inside the `layers` directory, but I don't find where others images (i.e. `cubemx-sdcard` or `cubemx-emmc`) are appended.

Comment: It depends on your setup, but for me I have my own layer with device specific profiles under `conf/machine/mymachine.conf` where I have (in my case a i.MX28) eg:

`MACHINEOVERRIDES =. "mx28:"`

I then set `MACHINE="mymachine"` in my local.conf

Comment: `MACHINE` was set, adding `stm32mp151a-sdcard` to `MACHINEOVERRIDES` removed the error. I guess that should be an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the wanted name of the machine as a target to build, i.e.:

```
MACHINE=stm32mp151a-sdcard bitbake <image>
```

This way, the UBOOT_EXTLINUX_ROOT gets the non-empty value "root=/dev/mmcblk0p6" (from the UBOOT_EXTLINUX_ROOT_stm32mp151a-sdcard variant of the variable).